# How can I get directions?

Tags: android, gps

I want my position through GPS & from that I want to go another location so directly I click that location on the map. Then there should be a getdirection option so that I can get the direction.

How can I do this?

Comment: pick one item and search over the internet. Even SO contains many links regarding "Getting GPS Points", "Get Directions"...

Comment: i answerd similar questions very often, please search the forum before posting

Comment: Plus also check FAQ on how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lot's of examples on the web, here are a few.

- http://hejp.co.uk/android/android-gps-example/
- http://www.dominik-schenner.com/?p=149
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html